# Adding filter to DateHistogram aggregation in ruflin/elastica

Tags: elastica

Ok, I am a bit confused.

I create aggregation as follows:

```
$aggregation = new DateHistogram('clicks_by_day', 'date', 'day');
$query->addAggregation($aggregation);
```

Now in this aggregation, I want to apply range filter to this aggregation. (Clicks with price greater then 0).

So I am a bit confused how to actually do it? There is no setFilter method, which I though would be the way to do it.

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself, here how it works:

1. Create Filter:

   ```
       $filter = new Filter('paid', new Query\Range('price', ['gt' => 0]));
   ```
2. Create aggregation:

   `$aggregation = new DateHistogram('clicks_by_day', 'date', 'day');`
3. Add aggregation to filter:

   `$aggregation = $filter->addAggregation($aggregation);`

The last step returns the aggregation with filter applied. Ant it work as expected.